# Cannot make a MySQL connection in windows mobile 6 c#

Tags: c#, mysql, windows-mobile-6.5

I try to run this simple code and i get this error:
The type 'System.Data.Common.DbConnection' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly

```
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection("server info");
```

The error highlights "MySqlConnection"

Ive added the reference to the DLL

Any Idea's?

Comment: not sure how this would work, since windows mobile isn't a supported platform for MySQL.

Comment: What! really? is there another way?

Comment: you probably should describe a bit more about what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: Well trying to connect to MySQL database from a windows mobile 6.5
Ive done it successfully on a Windows application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MySQL connector for windows mobile is installed with standard MySQL connectiors for .NET

C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Connector Net 6.5.5\Assemblies\v2.0

see http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?38,577138,577228

You have to add a reference to MySql.Data.CF.dll to your project to use MySQL connector.

Comment: Ok i have added the MySql.Data.CF to my references but hasnt fixed bug, do i need another "using" line at the top?

Comment: New Error:
The Type 'MySqlConnection' exists in both 'v0.2\MySql.Data.dll' and 'v0.2\MySql.Data.CF.dll'